# Sylow Theorems not allowed alternative method to show $\lvert G\rvert = 20$ single subgroup $\lvert H\rvert = 5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that I can use the Sylow Theorems but I have not been taught that in class. For instance I know using the Sylow Theorems that if $\lvert G\rvert = 20$ and $\lvert H\rvert = 5$ then there is a single subgroup of order $5$ and thus it is normal. But how is this shown without the Sylow Theorems?

Comment: You seem to be asking two slightly different questions. The one about groups of order $20$ can probably be done without Sylow, though it becomes a bit cumbersome. In general, unless you assume more about $n$ and $m$, even Sylow will not suffice.

Comment: I edited it for a concrete example

Answer (score 3):

Consider the action of $G$ on the set of cosets $G/H$ by left multiplication. This induces a homomorphism
$$\phi:G\to \mathrm{Sym}(G/H)\cong S_4$$
As $|S_4|=24$, $S_4$ has no subgroups of order $20=|G|$. This means that $\ker\phi$ is nontrivial. Note that $\ker\phi\leq H$ since any $g\in \ker\phi$ must satisfy $gH=H$ (i.e. $g\in H$). Since $|H|=5$ and $\ker\phi\neq\{1\}$, we must have $\ker\phi=H$. This proves that $H$ is normal.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler: assume that $H$ is not normal, then $H$ has a *conjugate*, say $K$, with $H \neq K$. Observe that $H \cap K=1$. But then for the set $|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|}=25$, contradicting $|G|=20$.

Comment: That's a good one! Though, calculating $|HK|$ is not entirely trivial.

Comment: Yes but it is pretty standard in most textbooks.